# revoke certificate request

Tags: ios, certificate, ios-provisioning

I try to submit my iOS app for validation. Unfortunately i have this message after archiving the app on xcode and clic on the validate button :

"The private key for "xxxxxx" is not installed on this Mac"

but i can't export the profil from the device who created this certificate.

Can i revoke developement and distribution certificates from ios developer portal and create new ones?

i want to say that the actual certificate is the one used by another app to be submit. If i revoke, is there a risk if i want to update this app?